If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, does there exists a nonzero continuous function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $g(x)f(x)$ is monotone?
Is the following proposition true or false?

If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then there exists a not-everywhere-zero (i.e. $g\not\equiv 0$)
continuous function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},\ $ such that $g(x)f(x)$ is
monotonic.

I was thinking that $f(x)=$ The Weierstrass function, could be a counter-example, but I am not sure of it.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Conrad answered this in the comments: $f(x):=\sin x$ is a counter-example. It has zeros stretching to plus and minus infinity. So $g(x)f(x)$ has the same zeros as $f,$ so $f(x)g(x)$ cannot be monotonic unless $g(x)f(x)\equiv 0$ identically $\implies g$
must be zero identically also.
If we further impose that $f(x)>0\ \forall\ x,$ then the answer is affirmative, as $g=\frac{1}{f}\implies f(x)g(x)\equiv 1,$ which is monotonic.
